# Intltool with an autoconf-generated .desktop file

Tags: internationalization, gettext, gnome, autoconf, automake

In the [Emperor](https://github.com/tjol/emperor) project, I'm having some issues getting intltool to work when doing an out-of-tree build. When running `make check` out-of-tree, which is one of the things `make distcheck` does, intltool fails thus:

```
INTLTOOL_EXTRACT="/usr/bin/intltool-extract" XGETTEXT="/usr/bin/xgettext" srcdir=../../po /usr/bin/intltool-update --gettext-package emperor --pot
can't open ../../po/../data/emperor.desktop.in: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/intltool-extract line 212.
```

intltool is looking for `emperor.desktop.in`, which is listed in `po/POTFILES.in`, in the source tree. However, `emperor.desktop.in` is generated by the configure script from a file called `emperor.desktop.in.in`, in order to insert the installed executable path as configured by the user, and lands in the build tree.

These are the relevant `bootstrap.sh` lines:

```
echo +++ Running intltoolize ... &&
intltoolize --force --copy &&
cat >>po/Makefile.in.in <<EOF

../data/_column_names.h:
    cd ../data && \$(MAKE) _column_names.h

EOF
```

The setup code in `configure.ac`:

```
IT_PROG_INTLTOOL([0.35.0])

GETTEXT_PACKAGE=emperor
AC_SUBST(GETTEXT_PACKAGE)
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([GETTEXT_PACKAGE], ["$GETTEXT_PACKAGE"],
                                      [The domain to use with gettext])
AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT
```

`data/emperor.desktop.in` is listed in `AC_CONFIG_FILES`.

`data/Makefile.am` contains these lines:

```
desktopdir = $(datadir)/applications
desktop_in_files = emperor.desktop.in
desktop_DATA = $(desktop_in_files:.desktop.in=.desktop)
@INTLTOOL_DESKTOP_RULE@
```

and `po/POTFILES.in` contains the line

```
data/emperor.desktop.in
```

You can review all the details in the [public git repository](https://github.com/tjol/emperor) if you wish.

**Can I somehow tell intltool that this file will be located in the build tree, not in the source tree?** Otherwise, my options appear to be to break `make distcheck` (not a great option), or to ship a desktop file that doesn't include the full path and assumes that the executable is installed in the PATH. (just as messy, IMHO) - Any other options?

Comment: Can you show the configure.ac and Makefile.am code that you are using to call intltool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some further digging has brought me believe that the answer is: intltool does not support source files that aren't source files in the project. Ergo, any additional processing must be done after intltool is through

Intltool requires the lines in `POTFILES` to be relative to the (build-time) working directory. The file `POTFILES` is generated by the configure script from `POTFILES.in` with a simple `sed` script defined in the `IT_PO_SUBDIR` autoconf macro (called by `IT_PROG_INTLTOOL`) that simply prepends the relative location of the top-level source directory to the paths. Alas, modifying `POTFILES` does not help: the `intltool-extract` script does everything it can to get the source directory right. I don't believe files that are sometimes inside and sometimes outside the source tree can be supported without modifying intltool itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your source code you have `emperor.desktop.in.in`, which does not seem to be in any rule as a dependency.  That file has to be converted first to `emperor.desktop.in` and later to `emperor.desktop`, which does not seem to be the case in your `data/Makefile.am`.

```
desktopdir = $(datadir)/applications
desktop_in_in_files = emperor.desktop.in.in
desktop_in_files = $(desktop_in_in_files:.desktop.in.in=.desktop.in)
desktop_DATA = $(desktop_in_files:.desktop.in=.desktop)
@INTLTOOL_DESKTOP_RULE@

[...]
EXTRA_DIST =  \
    $(desktop_in_in_files) \
    [...]
```

`$(desktop_in_in_files)` contains `$(desktop_in_in_files)`, and Makefile will know how to deal with that.

Comment: This doesn't change anything. `emperor.desktop.in` is generated by the configure script, not by intltool or some other Makefile rule. Everything works fine in an in-tree build: `emperor.desktop.in` is created in the source tree (since it's identical to the build tree), and intltool finds it.